# How to pass parameters in an array of functions using a series of promises

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have the following functions of Promises:

```
const func1 = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('func1 start');
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('func1 complete');
        resolve('Hello');
    }, 1000);
});

const func2 = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('func2 start');
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('func2 complete');
        resolve('World');
    }, 2000);
});
```

And to execute those functions in series, I use:

```
const promiseSerial = funcs =>
  funcs.reduce((promise, func) =>
    promise.then(result => func().then(Array.prototype.concat.bind(result))),
    Promise.resolve([]))
```

And to call:

```
promiseSerial([func1, func2]).then(values => {
    console.log("Promise Resolved. " + values); // Promise Resolved. Hello, World
}, function(reason) {
    console.log("Promise Rejected. " + reason);
});
```

And everything works fine, because I can have an array of values in series according to the order of the functions.

So, my question is:

How can I pass parameters between functions? I mean, I want to pass a parameter from `func1` to `func2`. I have thought maybe in the `resolve`, but it does not works.

Any ideas???

Comment: you can (and do) pass the resolved result of `func1` to `func2` - that's about all you can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `func2()` replace

`const func2 = ()`

to

`const func2 = (PARAMETER)`

---

In `promiseSerial()` replace

`promise.then(result => func()`

to

`promise.then(result => func(result[0])`

---

`console.log` the `PARAMETER` in func2 will show you the string 'Hello'

---

---

To send parameter to `func1` and if you have multiple `funcs`

```js
const func1 = (FIRST_PARA) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  console.log('func1 start, the first parameter is ' + FIRST_PARA);
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('func1 complete');
    resolve('Hello');
  }, 1000);
});

const func2 = (FIRST_PARA, LAST_PARA) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  console.log('func2 start, the received last parameter is ' + LAST_PARA);
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('func2 complete');
    resolve('World');
  }, 2000);
});

const promiseSerial = (funcs, firstParameter) => funcs.reduce((promise, func) =>
promise.then(result => func(firstParameter, result[result.length - 1]).then(Array.prototype.concat.bind(result))), Promise.resolve([]))


var firstParameter = 12;

promiseSerial([func1, func2], firstParameter).then(values => {
  console.log("Promise Resolved. " + values); // Promise Resolved. Hello, World
}, function(reason) {
  console.log("Promise Rejected. " + reason);
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm needing. Thanks, works like a charms !

Comment: Only one more thing: How can I put a parameter to the first function?

Comment: Thanks my friend. Works perfectly !