# Passing parameters in an array of functions using a series of promises with bluebird

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I have the following functions of Promises:

```
const func1 = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('func1 start');
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('func1 complete');
        resolve('Hello');
    }, 1000);
});

const func2 = (param_from_func1) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('func2 start ' + param_from_func1); // Want to get the value 'Hello' here
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('func2 complete');
        resolve('World');
    }, 2000);
});
```

And to execute those functions in series, I use:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');

Promise.series = (promiseArr) => {
  return Promise.reduce(promiseArr, (values, promise) => {
    return promise().then((result) => {
      values.push(result); // And here, I don't know how I can modify this to pass parameters between functions
      return values;
    });
  }, []);
};
```

And to call:

```
Promise.series([func1, func2]).then(values => {
    console.log("Promise Resolved. " + values); // Promise Resolved. Hello, World
}, function(reason) {
    console.log("Promise Rejected. " + reason);
});
```

And everything works fine, because I can have an array of values in series according to the order of the functions.

So, I have two questions:

1. How can I pass a parameter from `func1` to `func2`?
2. How can I pass a parameter intially to `func1`, and from them to `func2`?

Comment: What do you mean by passing a parameter? What are you trying to do exactly? This sounds a bit XY problem... Can you explain a use-case?

Comment: One of these days I have made a similiar question, but without bluebird. You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46375133/2954267). But I can't get it work with bluebird. That's why I'm making a new question.

Comment: the answer would be the same then

Comment: @JaromandaX As I said before, I can't get it. Can you try, please?

Comment: Oh I see now ... Promise.series does the call to func1 for you, does it? Doesn't look like you tried anything, because you have no parameters on your function definitions

Comment: @JaromandaX I have edited my question to emphasize what I need with my first question. And about the second question, would be the same, only before call `Promise.serie`, declare a variable as first parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass on the previous result(s), then just spread the `values` array to the promise-returning function. Replace:

```
promise().then
```

with:

```
promise(...values).then
```

```js
const func1 = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('func1 start');
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('func1 complete');
        resolve('Hello');
    }, 1000);
});

const func2 = (param_from_func1) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('func2 start ' + param_from_func1); // Want to get the value 'Hello' here
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('func2 complete');
        resolve('World');
    }, 2000);
});

Promise.series = (promiseArr) => {
  return Promise.reduce(promiseArr, (values, promise) => {
    return promise(...values).then((result) => {
      values.push(result); // And here, I don't know how I can modify this to pass parameters between functions
      return values;
    });
  }, []);
};

Promise.series([func1, func2]).then(values => {
    console.log("Promise Resolved. " + values); // Promise Resolved. Hello, World
}, function(reason) {
    console.log("Promise Rejected. " + reason);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.5.0/bluebird.min.js"></script>
```

The [`spread syntax`] replaces the array by separate arguments, as if you had listed them separately. See [spread syntax for function calls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Spread_in_function_calls).

If you want to also pass a value to the first function, then you can specify it in the initial value passed to the `reduce` method. So then replace:

```
, []);
```

with:

```
, [some_value]);
```

Note that this value will then also be passed to the second function which will then receive two arguments instead of one. In case you want each function to only receive a single value, namely the one returned by the previous promise, and not all previous promises, then replace

```
promise(...values)
```

with

```
promise(values[values.length-1]).
```

That way they all get passed exactly one value.

Comment: `promise(...values).then` ! Ohhh, the three dots, what does mean?

Comment: It means that the array is replaced by separate arguments, as if you had listed them separately. If the array is empty the function receives no arguments, if the array has one element, it receives one, if two, then two, ...etc. See [spread syntax for function calls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Spread_in_function_calls).

Comment: Oh thanks for the explanation ! One more thing: What if I want to pass a parameter to the first function? Can you please, post and additional example with this

Comment: In that case put that value in the `reduce` initial value; so replace `, [])` with `, [some_value])`. Note that this value will then *also* be passed to the second function which will then receive two arguments instead of one. In case you want each function to *only* receive that value returned by the previous promise and not all previous promises, then replace `(...values)` with `(values[values.length-1])`. That way they all get passed exactly one value.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation ! It is very useful. If you want to edit the post, and add those examples, will be great !

Comment: Just to point that declaring `, [some_value]);` to pass a parameter to the first function, this parameter will be called as a part of the all values in the last `resolve`, I mean here: `console.log("Promise Resolved. " + values); // Promise Resolved. some_value, Hello, World`